# Mail Notification when Item is Out of Stock

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, stock

I am trying to achieve the following:

When an item is Out of Stock send an E-Mail Notification to the warehouse.
First question would be: what's the easiest and cleanest way to achieve this?!

My approach was:

I wrote an observer which fires on the `sales_order_save_after` event.
So basically after every order all Items in this order should be checked wether these are still in Stock after the order.

The Observer.php looks like this:

```
public function checkStock($observer)
{
    $active = Mage::getStoreConfig('chimney_notifystock/general/notification_enabled');
    if ($active == 1){

        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {

            $product = $item->getProduct();
            $stockItem = $product->getStockItem();

            if ($stockItem->getIsInStock() == 0) {
                $this->sendMail($product);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that obviously on `sales_order_save_after` the value of `is_in_stock` isn't set to 0 yet.
The `getIsInStock()` method always returns 1 so the `sendMail()` won't be executed.
Everything else works fine and the e-mail is sent correctly when I set the
 `if ($stockItem->getIsInStock() == 0)`
 to
 `if ($stockItem->getIsInStock() == 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use event because it will called after the updating table data.

```
 sales_order_save_commit_after
```

Comment: unfortunately for some reason this still doesn't work.
When I complete the order the Stock is reduced correctly and if the stock hits 0 the product is set to "out of stock" but when I request the "is in stock status" or the qty from within the `sales_order_save_commit_after` i still get the qty from before the order and the product isn't set to out of stock yet. So this must be happening somewehere later on

Comment: @Chaz did you tried to get new object of product data?

Comment: What do you mean? How do I do that? How do I have to adjust my Code?

Comment: @Chaz `$product = $item->getProductId();` you will get id here . load new product data with model and check you will get the updated data. maybe you get the out of stock data correctly.

Comment: When I load the $stockItem like this the qty gets updated like you said. The "is in stock" status however isn't any ideas when this happens?
Anyways I think I can work with it like that, thank you very much!